# Getting started with C++, Kinect and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to learn C++, get into image processing and Kinect development using the 1.8 version of Microsoft's SDK, OpenCV and Visual C++ 2010 Express. I followed the steps described [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~edwardz/tutorials/kinect/kinect0.html) (sans the OpenGL part) to 'include' the Kinect and OpenCV libraries, but I don't seem to be able to do so. I copied and pasted OpenCV's dlls into the build directory to get that working but I don't know what to do about the Kinect. Any clues on what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: A little bit more of info. I only have a main.cpp file with the following two lines at the top (is it called header guard?):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <NuiApi.h>
```

The second one makes the compiler yell at me:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'NuiApi.h': No such file or directory
```

Now these files should be reachable given the property sheets I configured earlier.

Comment: So I presume you're getting a bunch of link errors. You should have a look [through here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). We can't do much to help beyond that with the little information that you've provided.

Comment: Updating the question to provide more info

Comment: You need to make sure you have #include directories and lib directories setup properly in your solution properties. It sounds like wherever you are linking to does not have NuiApi.h, or you are not linking at all.

Comment: My advice is to concentrate on learning C++ at somewhat decent level, then go for the image processing and Kinect. Learning a language in a specific content (OpenCV, Kinect) has the huge advantage that it will limit your knowledge on that specific language and you will have difficulties to adapt if something else comes your way.

Comment: @user2970916 Checked the lib directories and changed accordingly, now I'm getting a bunch of compile-time errors coming from NuiApi.h   ... I don't know how to react to this

Comment: @rbaleksandar Thanks for the advice! Sadly my current job makes going at a slower pace impossible for me

Comment: The error states that the compiler didn't find **NuiApi.h** in the **include** directories. Check the project properties, and make sure to add that directory to `Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >> General >> Additional Include Directories`.